# SharePoint 2010 Checked out pdf

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In sharepoint 2010 there is a feature that allows a site owner to view all checked out files using the option "Manage files which have no checked in version".

I noticed that when a pdf file in the document library is checked out, either on purpose or accident, the pdf is not listed in the "managed files which have no checked in version".

Anyone familiar with not being able to managed known checked out files not being listed in the "Manage files which have no checked in version"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Manage files which have no checked in version" lists only documents which have been uploaded but have never been checked in. For example if a file is in version 1.0 then its checked out that file will not be listed in "Manage files which have no checked in version".

Comment: There was a feature in 2007 "manage checked out files". Does this function the same way you described the feature in 2010? If so, is there a way to list checked out files? Thanks

Comment: I was talking for SP 2010. You can filter a view by column "Checked out to" to see only the files in checked out state.